# smallest $\sigma$-algebra on a set of singletons

Tags: measure-theory

I have an exercise in my measure and integration theory course and I'm a little bit stuck with the $\sigma$-rings and $\sigma$-algebras. The exercise goes as follows:

Let $X$ be a set and $\varepsilon = \{\{x\}\,|\,x \in X\}$. Determine $\sigma(\varepsilon)$, the smallest $\sigma$-algebra that contains epsilon.

I know that $\varepsilon = \{\{x\}\,|\,x \in X\}$ is the set that contains the singeltons as elements.

My first problem when defining the $\sigma$-algebra is whether it has to contain the empty set AND the set $X$, OR the empty set and the set $\varepsilon$? Because this is one of three conditions for forming a $\sigma$-algebra.

The second condition, that $\sigma(\varepsilon)$ has to contain the complement of a subset $A \in \sigma(\varepsilon)$, is (I think) clear for me. But then the third condition, that it has to contain the the union of all subsets of $\sigma(\varepsilon)$, is also unclear. I am not sure how to "build" this union.

Comment: It has to contain $\emptyset$ and $X$ to be a $\sigma$-algebra. For the second question: is there any further information given about $X$?

Comment: I suspect the exercise is asking for the smallest sigma-algebra on $X$ which includes (contains as a subset) $\epsilon$, all the singleton subsets of $X$.

Comment: Answer to mag: No, there is no further information about X.
Answer to @hardmath: So if i understand it correctly, everytime when you have $\sigma$($\varepsilon$) it means that you are looking for a $\sigma$-algebra that CONTAINS $\varepsilon$ BUT it can be ON an arbitrary set X?

Comment: Here $X$ is the set we started with, and $\varepsilon$ is defined in terms of $X$.  If $X$ is finite or countable, the inclusion $\varepsilon \subset \sigma(\varepsilon)$ compels $\sigma(\varepsilon)$ to contain all subsets of $X$, so we would get the full powerset of $X$.  A bigger $X$ is more interesting.

Comment: @hardmath how does it follow from $\varepsilon$ being a subset of $\sigma$($\varepsilon$) that $\sigma$($\varepsilon$) contains all subsets of X ? Is it because you have to take all possible unions of elements of $\varepsilon$ in order to satisfy the condition for $\sigma$($\varepsilon$) ?

Comment: Note that I said this is so if $X$ is finite or countable.  A sigma-algebra is closed under taking the union of countably many sets.  If $X$ is countable, then any subset of $X$ is a countable (or finite) union of its singleton subsets.

Comment: @hardmath I noted that, thank you! So just for the moment let's assume X is countable or finite
1. Is my reasoning from my previous comment correct as to why $\sigma$($\varepsilon$) contains all subsets of X ?
2. From my understanding up to this point, $\sigma$($\varepsilon$) contains the following elements: 
i) The empty set
ii) all elements of $\varepsilon$, i.e. it contains $\varepsilon$
iii) all possible unions of the elements of $\varepsilon$
Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, that much is true if $X$ is finite or countably infinite.

Comment: @hardmath ok, thanks! Now I have 2 more questions:
1. One of the conditions for a $\sigma$-algebra is that for an arbitrary A $\epsilon$ $\sigma$($\varepsilon$), $\sigma$($\varepsilon$) has also have to contain the complement of A. Where are the complements in my case? Are they a part of all possible unions of the elements of $\varepsilon$ ?
2. If I have determined  $\sigma$($\varepsilon$), how do I find the SMALLEST $\sigma$($\varepsilon$) ?

Comment: What I was hinting at is that the problem is only mildly interesting when $X$ is at most countable, since any sigma-algebra containing all singleton subsets of $X$ will necessarily be the powerset of $X$, which is closed under taking complements.

Answer (score 2):

Clearly, $\sigma(\epsilon)$ must contain all countable sets. For if we have a set $\{a_i \mid i \in S\}$ where $S \subseteq \mathbb{N}$, then define $\{b_i\}_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$ by $b_i$ to be $\{a_i\}$ if $i \in S$, $\emptyset$ otherwise. Then $\{a_i \mid i \in S\} = \bigcup\limits_{i \in \mathbb{N}} b_i$.

Thus, we see that $\sigma(\epsilon)$ must also contain all sets whose complement is countable. For if $A$ has a countable complement, then $A^c \in \sigma(\epsilon)$, and thus $A = (A^c)^c \in \sigma(\epsilon)$.

The question is: is this all of the elements of $\sigma(\epsilon)$?

In order to show the answer is "yes", you must demonstrate that $\{A \subseteq X \mid A$ is countable or $A^c$ is countable$\}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra. I'll leave that as an exercise.

Comment: Thank you for the reply!
Does the "we see that $\sigma$($\varepsilon$) must also contain all sets whose complements countable" follow form "$\sigma$($\varepsilon$) must contain ALL countable sets" ?

Comment: @syphracos Yes, that's exactly the argument I'm making.

Comment: okay. Could you the basically write the union of b_i in such a way that b_i $\epsilon$ {b_i , b_i ^c}, so it's either b_i or the complement of b_i ? I'm sorry for my notations, I have to learn MathJax